# How to show input button when hover over input text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

### What I want to happen

- When hover over `Worksheet-Problem` input text, I want `.button-add`
  to show up and the user be able to click on it. When the user hovers
  away from the `Worksheet-Problem` input text, I want `.button-add` to
  fade away.
- When hover over `.button-bullet`, I want `.button-bullet`
  to disappear and`.button-remove` to fade in its place

I feel like this should be simple enough. I might be using the incorrect jQuery functions.

### What is actually happening

`.button-add` keeps blinking and coordination between`.button-remove` fadingIn and `.button-bullet` disappearing is a fail.

*Add Button Glitch*
[image]

*Remove Button Glitch*
[image]

### My code

I set the `display` of the `.button-add` and `.button-remove` to `none`. And then I toggled their `display`, as well as `.button-bullet`'s `display`, using `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`.

*HTML*

```
.button-add, .button-remove{
    display: none;
}
```

*jQuery*

```
$("input[type='text'][name='Worksheet-Problem']").focus(function(){
        $(".button-add").fadeIn(300);  
    })
    $("input[type='text'][name='Worksheet-Problem']").hover(function(){
        $(".button-add").fadeIn(300);
    })
    $("input[type='text'][name='Worksheet-Problem']").mouseout(function(){
        $(".button-add").fadeOut(300);
    })
    $(".button-bullet").hover(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $(".button-remove").fadeIn(300);
    })
    $(".button-remove").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut(300);
        $(".button-bullet").fadeIn(300);
    })
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/14ongm/p6tegtcx/4/)

Comment: Consider triggering your event when the user is interacting with the wrapper (in this case `form-group`) as that might provide better transitioning as they move back and forth.  You can probably also reduce your code and use `fadeToggle` instead of `fadeOut` and `fadeIn`

Comment: I will update your fiddle to the desired result give me 15 min i will post an answer for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("input[type='text'][name='Worksheet-Problem']").closest('.row').hover(function()      {
        $(".button-add").fadeToggle(300);
    })
    $(".button-bullet").closest('.input-group-btn').hover(function(){
        $('.button-bullet').toggle();
        $(".button-remove").toggle();
    })

    $(".button-add").click(function(){
        console.log("Add-Button pressed");
    })
    $(".button-remove").click(function(){
        console.log("Remove-Button pressed");
    })
})
```